# Is there a way to change the shell that opens when using keybinding Ctrl + Shift + c in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've noticed this code in the keyboard shortcut settings.

`{ "key": "ctrl+shift+c", "command":"workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole" },`

I was wondering, instead of opening cmd.exe, can I change it to open Powershell?

Answer (score 6):

Starting in v1.1.0, we can now configure the external shell.

Before version 1.6.1, there was only one setting.

```
"externalTerminal.windowsExec": "powershell"
```

Starting with version 1.6.1, there is an external and internal terminal setting. Using the value "%COMSPEC%", one could instead change their COMSPEC environment variable.

```
// The path of the shell that the terminal uses on Windows. When using shells shipped with Windows (cmd, PowerShell or Bash on Ubuntu), prefer C:\Windows\sysnative over C:\Windows\System32 to use the 64-bit versions.
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",

// The path of the shell that the terminal uses on Windows. When using shells shipped with Windows (cmd, PowerShell or Bash on Ubuntu), prefer C:\Windows\sysnative over C:\Windows\System32 to use the 64-bit versions.
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

I found, however, that it opens the 32bit Powershell.exe. Which, for me, did not have its execution policy set. So I set it using the following...

I elevated my permissions (Powershell's version of sudo):

```
Start-Process Powershell -Verb Runas
```

Then, in the new elevated Powershell window:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: `terminal.external.windowsExec` in 1.6.1

Comment: Nice. It now defaults to %COMSPEC% so it can be configured via environment variables. I wonder what kind of chaos changing that from CMD.exe will cause.

Comment: If you are using the 64 Bit Visual Studio Code then don't use sysnative as Sysnative is a virtual folder, a special alias, that can be used to access the 64-bit System32 folder from a 32-bit application or script. Use instad the System32 folder.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, the customization is more geared towards changing the keys / conditions that trigger the actions, rather than adding new actions.

It would be great to be able to create custom actions too - and the Visual Studio Code team are interested in hearing ideas on their [User Voice site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code).

I have added a [suggestion for custom actions](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7777677-keyboard-shortcuts-custom-actions).

Answer (score 0):

There is still no setting yet as of February 2016, but you can use the `CodeShell` extension and once installed use `Ctrl-Alt-P` to launch a PowerShell window at the root of the project folder.